# PDFKit Can't load image in browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser, browserify, pdfkit

I'm working with [PDFKit](http://pdfkit.org) to generate a PDF in the browser, and then send the blob data of that PDF to a new tab for the user to download. I really like PDFKit...it's pretty slick.

However, I'm running into an issue when I try and use the [`PDFDocument.image()`](http://pdfkit.org/docs/images.html) function to *"draw"* an image file:

> Uncaught TypeError: `fs.readFileSync` is not a function

I'm pretty familiar with Node, and so I recognized that method signature immediately - the browser doesn't have `fs` natively! I'm less familiar with Browserify, and opted to instead use the [pre-built version of PDFKit](https://github.com/devongovett/pdfkit/releases) to avoid having to integrate another dependency that I'm not even familiar with.

My only guess is that the developers of PDFKit haven't included a working fallback for using this particular feature in the browser without Browserify - would using Browserify even give me access to the `fs` module (again, never used it)? Is that my only option here? Am I missing a particular step required to get this feature working?

Currently I'm including the following JS files as dependencies for my `generate_pdf.js` file:

- `pdfkit.js`
- `blob-stream.js`

Is there a module that emulates `fs` that I also need? I'm not seeing that documented, but it's been a long day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there are some libraries (like [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/level-fs-browser) or [this](https://github.com/jvilk/BrowserFS)), but I would highly recommend to write your own `fs.readFileSync`.

Since you're not likely to access client's filesystem from the browser anyway, using some existing solution would imply adding an abstraction level, etc.

So, *probably* the simplest and the easiest solution would be to add

```
var fs = {
  readFileSync: (path) => {
    // magic
  }
}
```

Why *probably*? Well...

1. If there are usages of many `fs` functions, you'd obviously want to  do it with some library
2. Synchronous requests. I guess you're loading images from some url, so you'll  have to use synchronous requests in the implementation of `fs.readFileSync` to achieve the desired result. It's not like a big deal, but you'll get warnings in console.

P.S. sorry, but there's a hight probability that you'll face more issues with that because it's much more common to create pdfs on the server-side. Wy not move to the backend? ;)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'm not sure why PDFKit is using `readFileSync` to get an image from the server (I'm not trying to access the client filesystem). I don't think I'll be rolling my own :p The reason I'm doing this on the client is that I'm much more comfortable with JavaScript than I am PHP, and this is for a WordPress site. I think what I'll try to do is spin up a simple Node server to handle the PDF generation.

Comment: Well, you can just generate a pdf in a nodejs process invoked from php with, let's say, ``exec`` - no need to set up a server ;)